# Meshing Example -> mesh errors | Project Tango | Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, google-project-tango, marching-cubes

I am trying to use the [Meshing Example](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-meshing) from the Project Tango Unity3d-Demos to detect collision with real world objects in my application. However, there are a lot of small errors in the mesh.
These floating "bubbles" are counter productive to what I am trying to accomplish, but I could not find a way to change this in the [Meshing script](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/ExperimentalMeshBuilder/Scripts/DynamicMeshManager.cs).
[image: Screenshot: Meshing Unity]

How do I have to modify the script to find and remove vertices that are to close together and not connected to the main mesh?

**Updated results using the Izar release:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just released a brand new meshing pipeline in Unity. The bubble is an artifact of the pointcloud. In the new Unity Tango SDK (Izar release), there's a `space clearing` checkbox on `Tango Manager` under `Enable 3D reconstruction`. Turning on that will actively remove these artifacts as the meshing is running.

Comment: Thank you very much! But even though the results are MUCH better, it's still possible to generate unwanted artifacts by walking from one room to another and back again (see my updated question).

Comment: Hi RUB3N, I believe if you turn on `space clearing` and scan the area again, the artifacts in the space will go away. `space clearing` is relying on several depth sensor readings to remove artifacts. For example, if the meshing created some artifacts during the observation, but the area is not observed again, the artifacts will keep staying there until next observation of the area occurs.